# .NET Maui Event Handlers not being added at XAML Level

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui

I'm starting to wonder if it's just some setting somewhere, but adding event handlers to controls in XAML is proving to be frustrating in .NET Maui. For instance, if I just want to create this button:

```
<Button Text="Good job"
 x:Name="GoodJobButton"
 Clicked="GoodJobButton_Clicked"/>
```

It will create a perfectly fine Event Handler in the code behind:

```
private void GoodJobButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Do cool magic
}
```

But it's not actually attaching the handler to the control. I get an error unless I do this in the constructor:

```
GoodJobButton.Clicked += GoodJobButton_Clicked;
```

And WOW, I don't want to have to do that for everything I have in this app. I'm migrating over from Xamarin, and this is pretty much the last problem I have to solve until I'm off and running again.

Anyway, please tell me this is a bug or something. Otherwise, shame me if you must. Thanks!

Comment: this works fine for me.  Have you tried restarting VS, cleaning the solution, wiping bin/obj folders, etc?

Comment: @Jason Tried everything but wiping the folders, did that, restarted, still the same issue. Thanks, though!

Comment: *"I get an error"* - please add to question the text of the error.

Comment: No bug that I know of and this has been working for me since forever. Could you elaborate a bit more or maybe add a little reproduction project?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". When I click the button, that is the error I get. Like I said, the event handler isn't being added to the control's Clicked event, so it doesn't know what to do when it's clicked

Comment: If it isn't attached, it should simply do nothing - not sure how you are getting that error. Start a new Maui project. Make the simplest possible test case. Problem still happen? If so, add to question the complete xaml and xaml.cs of the test page. Also, testing on Windows or Android?